# Make curved line between two points in R

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet

I want to draw a curved line between two points (representing a flight route) in R. I have used the following code:

```
library(mapsapi)
library(leaflet)


# Your private key
key = "XXX"

# Getting the geolocations from the Google Maps Directions API
addresses = c("Mexico City", "Bangkok")

doc = mp_geocode(
  addresses = addresses,
  key = key
)

# Extract points from the response
point = mp_get_points(doc)

# Geocode the addresses using tidygeocoder
addresses1 <- tibble(singlelineaddress = c("MEX", "BKK")) %>% 
  geocode(address = singlelineaddress, method = 'arcgis') %>% 
  transmute(id = singlelineaddress,
            lon = long,
            lat = lat)

# Visualize using leaflet
palette = colorFactor(palette = "Set2", domain = point$location_type)

# Generate a curved line between the two points
trip <- gcIntermediate(
  p1 = c(addresses1$lon[1], addresses1$lat[1]),
  p2 = c(addresses1$lon[2], addresses1$lat[2]),
  n = 30,
  addStartEnd = TRUE
)

# Visualize using leaflet
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = point) %>%
  addPolylines(
    lng = trip[, "lon"],
    lat = trip[, "lat"],
    color = "blue",
    smoothFactor = 0
  )
```

However, the line is not curved (see the picture below).

How do I fix that?

[image]